# Is saying something you do not mean always irony?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The other day someone told me that it is irony every time you say something you don’t really mean. At first, I thought that wasn’t correct, but when I thought about it, I wasn’t quite sure. Is that correct, or does the intention of the speaker have to be that the other person should interpret it as the opposite. For example, teasing your friends. It works well because your friend knows that you do not really mean it. If they thought you actually meant it, they would probably be offended. But when you are saying it, your intention is to tease your friend, not to emphasize the opposite of the literal meaning.

If your friend tells a story about a TV show that he never really understood as a kid, and you say ”yeah, but you’ve always been kind of stupid”.

There, you are teasing your friend. Your friend understands it is a joke because they know you and know that you do not mean it. It relies on the fact that it isn't your real opinion. Is it irony just by the fact that you do not mean it, and the other person knows you do not mean it, even if the point of the comment is to tease your friend?

(Teasing is just an example. It could also be when telling a joke that everyone knows isn’t 100 % true, but you are saying it to paint a funny situation.)

Is it really correct to categorize those comments as *irony*?

Comment: Irony is pretending not to know something is untrue more than saying something you do not mean.

Comment: it’s irony when you make that comment in front of another friend who knows that you’re probably not as smart as the friend you’re “teasing”

Comment: There are different forms of irony. The technical term for saying something when one knows the opposite is true is _antiphrasis_, though even this has been narrowed so that an ironic / jocular flavour is implied. Lying is an obvious example of saying the opposite of what is true, but with the intent to deceive. It grades into white lies and kidding (no real malice involved). Verbal irony is on the other hand not intended to deceive; it is often comedic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is it correct to say that what distinguishes verbal irony from a joke is that, with verbal irony, you want them to realize the opposite meaning of the literal meaning, while when you're kidding, you kind of want to deceive the other person (but in a harmless way)? So if a joke is supposed to be understood as the opposite of the literal meaning, it uses irony?

Comment: Agreed as far as )?. A joke may be a practical joke, a pun, a witty and funny new observation/slant ... it need not involve antiphrasis at all.

Comment: Verbal irony is closely related with sarcasm. See the examples [here](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-irony.html). Generally, the fact that it's the opposite of what you mean is obvious to the audience from the context.